# Implement "knowledgeable people" in Community?

Tags: customer-community, topics

It seems that **knowledgeable people** exists in Chatter but not in my Customer Community (using Napili template). Any steps I'm missing? Do I need Work.com licences?

Comment: What template are you using for your communities?

Comment: Napili Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see there is a standard component in Topic Detail for this .Please check screen shot below .This is present by default in Napili

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see this component, but it displays nothing.

Comment: You will need to mark few people knowledgeable to see results .It working fine .Have you marked few people knowledable

Comment: No, how can I do it?

Comment: Login in as one of user and try commenting on a Topic or answering questions posting on a Topic .You will see users on their profile the topic being added .Endrose further .Check my screenshots

Comment: Help article ,in case this helps you https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_topics_knowledgeable_people.htm&language=en